# Unstable symbolic expectation of gaussian distribution on absolute values?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, symbolic

**Context**

I use mathematica 11.3 and 12.

11.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)

12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)

I am interested in evaluating the following integral

```
  exp = Expectation[
  Abs[x] Abs[y], {x, y} \[Distributed]MultinormalDistribution[
   {0, 0}, {{a, c}, {c, b}}]]// FullSimplify[#, c > 0] &;
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(*    (Sqrt[a b-c^2] (2 a b-c^2)+a b c cot^-1(Sqrt[a b-c^2]/c))/([Pi] a b)   *)

If I then evaluate the same integral but while giving a,b,c values first I get

```
  expN =  Expectation[Abs[x] Abs[y], {x, y} \[Distributed] 
   MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {{1, 1/4}, {1/4, 2}}]] // N
```

(*  0.914421 *)

But if I take the symbolic result and evaluate it with those same values I get

```
 exp /. {a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 1/4} // N
```

(*  0.886433  *)

**Question**

> Can anyone reproduce what seems to be a bug?

Can you suggest any workaround?

**Update**

In view of the comments below I would like to label this issue as a bug.
The fact that mathematica yields different answers to a given analytical integral
as a function of evaluation time qualifies as a bug IMHO.

> Any objection?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. On my machine, `exp /. {a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 1/4} // N` also produces `0.914421`. Maybe because `exp` is actually `(2 (Sqrt[a b - c^2] + c ArcTan[c/Sqrt[a b - c^2]]))/\[Pi]` instead of what you write. Using `$Version == "12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)"`.

Comment: Windows 10, *Mathematica* 11.3:  I also get 0.886433.

Comment: @Roman I don't understand why you get a different expression.

Comment: But if one uses `exp = Expectation[
   Abs[x] Abs[y], {x, y} \[Distributed] 
    MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {{a, c}, {c, b}}], 
   Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0, c > 0}] // FullSimplify`, then the substitution works fine and one gets a different symbolic result:  $\frac{4 \sqrt{a b-c^2}+2 c \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{c}{\sqrt{a b-c^2}}\right)-2 c \cot ^{-1}\left(\frac{c}{\sqrt{a b-c^2}}\right)+\pi  c}{2 \pi }$

Comment: Cannot reproduce it in v12.0 on Windows 10: both results are $0.914421$.

Comment: @user64494 you should write your comment as an answer providing a workaround? it turns out your answer is equal to Roman's.

Comment: OK, I get both results, `0.886433` and `0.914421`! I can only think that some of the `TimeConstrained[]` computations sometimes abort and sometimes not.

Comment: @MichaelE2:  In three executions I obtain $0.914421$ as both the results.

Comment: I guess so.  I don't see why it should produce a wrong result (except that I know symbolic integration is fraught such issues).  The nondeterministic behavior of `TimeConstrained[]` seems less a bug (to me).

Comment: @user64494 In more than a dozen executions, I've gotten `0.886433` three times, two of them while using `TracePrint`; the rest of the results have been `0.914421`.

Comment: I revise my post and now agree with @MichaelE2. Delayed-defining `exp := Expectation[Abs[x] Abs[y], {x, y} \[Distributed] MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {{a, c}, {c, b}}]]` and then executing `A = Table[exp, {10}];` I get seven different answers out of ten attempts (`Length[DeleteDuplicates[A]]` gives 7), some of which give a numerical 0.914421 and some a 0.886433.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)" *)
```

Checking by comparing the results for the distribution defined with [`MultinormalDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MultinormalDistribution.html) and [`BinormalDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BinormalDistribution.html)

```
Clear["Global`*"]

distMN = MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {{a, c}, {c, b}}];
```

The implied assumptions (i.e., required for a valid distribution) are

```
assumeMN = DistributionParameterAssumptions[distMN]

(* a > 0 && b > 0 && c ∈ Reals && a b - c^2 > 0 *)
```

Note that this is different than assuming `c > 0`.

Similarly,

```
distBN = BinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {Sqrt[a], Sqrt[b]}, c/Sqrt[a*b]];

assumeBN = DistributionParameterAssumptions[distBN]

(* Sqrt[a] > 0 && Sqrt[b] > 0 && -1 < c/Sqrt[a b] < 1 *)
```

Verifying that the distributions are equivalent under either form of the assumptions:

```
Simplify[
  PDF[distMN, {x, y}] == PDF[distBN, {x, y}],
  assumeMN] &&
 Simplify[
  PDF[distMN, {x, y}] == PDF[distBN, {x, y}],
  assumeBN]

(* True *)

expMNgen = Assuming[assumeMN,
  Expectation[Abs[x] Abs[y], {x, y} \[Distributed] distMN] // FullSimplify]
```

[image]

Assuming `c > 0` (i.e., positive correlation coefficient) with `MultinormalDistribution`

```
expMN = expMNgen // FullSimplify[#, c > 0] &
```

[image]

```
params = {a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 1/4};

(expMN /. params) // N

(* 0.914421 *)

expMNN = Expectation[Abs[x] Abs[y],
   {x, y} \[Distributed] (distMN /. params)] // N

(* 0.914421 *)

expBNgen = Assuming[assumeBN,
  Expectation[Abs[x] Abs[y], {x, y} \[Distributed] distBN] // FullSimplify]
```

[image]

Despite the different forms, `expMNgen` and `expBNgen` are equal

```
expMNgen == expBNgen // FullSimplify

(* True *)
```

Assuming `c > 0` with `BinormalDistribution`

```
expBN = expBNgen // Simplify[#, c > 0] &
```

[image]

As expected, `expMN` and `expBN` are equal for `c > 0`

```
FullSimplify[expBN == expMN, c > 0]

(* True *)

expBN /. params // N

(* 0.914421 *)

expBNN = Expectation[Abs[x] Abs[y],
   {x, y} \[Distributed] (distBN /. params)] // N

(* 0.914421 *)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Have you noticed any instability in the answer when you request it more than once? It seems this is the most serious concern here.